# Couldn't set tty to PPP discipline: Operation not permitted

Tags: centos, vpn, mikrotik, ppp

настраиваю VPN между Centos (server) и Mikrotik (client) Помогите разобраться, в чем проблема?
Конфигурации служб:

/etc/xl2tpd/xl2tpd.conf

```
[global]
    port = 1701
    debug avp = yes
    debug network = yes
    debug packet = yes
    debug state = yes
    debug tunnel = yes

[lns default]
    ip range = 192.168.41.10-192.168.41.250
    local ip = 192.168.41.1
    require chap = yes
    refuse pap = yes
    require authentication = yes
    name = l2tpd
    pppoptfile = /etc/ppp/options.xl2tpd
    length bit = yes
    ppp debug = yes
```

/etc/ppp/options.xl2tpd

```
ipcp-accept-local
ipcp-accept-remote
ms-dns  8.8.8.8
ms-dns  1.1.1.1
noccp
auth
#obsolete: crtscts
idle 1800
mtu 1410
mru 1410
nodefaultroute
debug

proxyarp
connect-delay 5000
```

при попытке подключиться pppd в логах следующая ошибка:

```
Dec 14 20:58:45 instance-test12 xl2tpd: xl2tpd[3377]: control_finish: message type is Incoming-Call-Connected(12).  Tunnel is 1883, call is 1.
Dec 14 20:58:45 instance-test12 xl2tpd: xl2tpd[3377]: Call established with 195.248.187.71, PID: 19553, Local: 30546, Remote: 1, Serial: 1882
Dec 14 20:58:45 instance-test12 pppd[19553]: pppd 2.4.5 started by root, uid 0
Dec 14 20:58:45 instance-test12 pppd[19553]: Couldn't set tty to PPP discipline: Operation not permitted
Dec 14 20:58:45 instance-test12 pppd[19553]: Exit.
Dec 14 20:58:45 instance-test12 xl2tpd: xl2tpd[3377]: child_handler : pppd exited for call 1 with code 1
Dec 14 20:58:45 instance-test12 xl2tpd: xl2tpd[3377]: call_close: Call 30546 to 195.248.187.71 disconnected
```

вывод команды find /lib/modules/$(uname -r) -name *ppp*

```
/lib/modules/5.4.17-2102.206.1.el7uek.x86_64/kernel/drivers/net/ppp
/lib/modules/5.4.17-2102.206.1.el7uek.x86_64/kernel/drivers/net/ppp/ppp_async.ko.xz

/lib/modules/5.4.17-2102.206.1.el7uek.x86_64/kernel/drivers/net/ppp/ppp_deflate.ko.xz

/lib/modules/5.4.17-2102.206.1.el7uek.x86_64/kernel/drivers/net/ppp/ppp_generic.ko.xz

/lib/modules/5.4.17-2102.206.1.el7uek.x86_64/kernel/drivers/net/ppp/ppp_mppe.ko.xz

/lib/modules/5.4.17-2102.206.1.el7uek.x86_64/kernel/drivers/net/ppp/ppp_synctty.ko.xz

/lib/modules/5.4.17-2102.206.1.el7uek.x86_64/kernel/drivers/net/ppp/pppoe.ko.xz

/lib/modules/5.4.17-2102.206.1.el7uek.x86_64/kernel/drivers/net/ppp/pppox.ko.xz

/lib/modules/5.4.17-2102.206.1.el7uek.x86_64/kernel/drivers/net/wan/hdlc_ppp.ko.xz

/lib/modules/5.4.17-2102.206.1.el7uek.x86_64/kernel/net/atm/pppoatm.ko.xz

/lib/modules/5.4.17-2102.206.1.el7uek.x86_64/kernel/net/l2tp/l2tp_ppp.ko.xz
```

вывод команды: lsmod | grep ppp

```
l2tp_ppp               28672  0

l2tp_netlink           24576  1 l2tp_ppp

l2tp_core              32768  2 l2tp_ppp,l2tp_netlink

pppox                  16384  1 l2tp_ppp

ppp_generic            40960  2 pppox,l2tp_ppp

slhc                   16384  1 ppp_generic
```

Comment: от имени какого пользователя запускаете pppd на клиентской стороне?

Comment: ну и на всякий случай приложите к вопросу вывод `$ find /lib/modules/$(uname -r) -name \*ppp\*`

Comment: Вывод добавил в вопрос, запускается как я понимаю от рута:
Dec 15 11:21:01 instance-test12 pppd[1571]: pppd 2.4.5 started by root, uid 0

Comment: ошибка может быть следствием незагруженности модуля ppp_generic. ну а так как вы используете в качестве транспорта l2tp, то нужен и модуль l2tp_ppp, в зависимостях у которого должен быть и тот же ppp_generic. проверьте, загружены ли эти модули, и если нет, то загрузите.

Comment: так он загружен, все модули есть

Comment: вот [этот ioctl](https://github.com/ppp-project/ppp/blob/eff574c871822c7e2788aa8a928f2480fa7a6cb3/pppd/sys-linux.c#L462) завершается ошибкой «Operation not permitted». сами собой напрашивающиеся предположения: а) pppd выполняется от имени рядового пользователя и б) не загружен нужный модуль. посмотрите, какие у вас в системе модули относятся к «дисциплинам tty»: `$ grep tty.*disc /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/modules.alias`. возможно, какой-то из них надо будет загрузить. по идее, исходя из приложенного вами списка, это может быть ppp_synctty или ppp_async

Comment: Все модулю присутствуют, как бы проверить, от какого пользователя он запускается и как этим управлять?

Comment: `Все модулю присутствуют` — в приведённом вами выводе lsmod не упоминается ppp_synctty или ppp_async. `как бы проверить, от какого пользователя` — это смотрите в логе pppd. опция debug у вас вроде бы присутствует, так что программа должна быть весьма разговорчивой. значительно более разговорчивой, чем видно из приведённого вами лога. вероятно, должен быть ещё один лог-файл, именно с выводом pppd.

Comment: на крайний случай, если ioctl, конфигурирующий tty, так и останется невыполнимым, можно попробовать добавить опцию `notty`. в man-е про неё написано, что она «increases  the  latency  and  CPU overhead». ну, а что делать?

Comment: Спасибо, вечером подробней попробую

Comment: ppp не многословен)) "Couldn't set tty to PPP discipline: Operation not permitted" больше ничего